# How to calculate new mean if population is unknown?

Tags: average, descriptive-statistics

I have three values

- Mean (population mean, not from sample)

  $\bar{x} = 3$
- Number of elements in population (number of values in original set)

  $n = 15$
- A new value

  $x_{(n+1)} = 7$

What is the correct formula to calculate the new mean? I would calculate it like this

$$
\bar{x}' = x_{(n+1)} * \frac{1}{(n+1)} + \bar{x} * \frac{n}{(n+1)}
$$

which can be shortened

$$
= \frac{x_{(n+1)}}{(n+1)} + \frac{\bar{x} * n}{(n+1)} = \frac{x_{(n+1)} + \bar{x} * n}{(n+1)}
$$

Is that the correct formula? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your formula works, and you can apply it to the case at hand.

$\bar x$ is the "starting" population mean, $n$ the population count, $\bar x'$ is the *new* population mean. Then

$$\bar{x}' = \frac{\bar x \cdot n + x_{n+1}}{n+1} = \frac{3\cdot 15 + 7}{15+1} = \frac{52}{16} = 3.25$$

Comment: Okay, thanks. Due to your reputation I'll assess your answer as trustworthy ;-)